# Pandas Plotting from Pivot Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

I am basically trying to reproduce climate diagrams showing mean temperature and precipitation over the year for various locations.

I've generated a pivot table from my csv the following way:

```
data = pd.read_csv("05_temp_rain_v2.csv")
pivot = data.pivot_table(["rain(mm)","temp(dC)"], ["loc","month"])
```

sample data in text form:

```
loc,lat,long,year,month,rain(mm),temp(dC)
Adria_-_Bellombra,45.011129,12.034126,1994,1,45.6,4.6  
Adria_-_Bellombra,45.011129,12.034126,1994,2,31.4,4  
Adria_-_Bellombra,45.011129,12.034126,1994,3,1.6,10.7  
Adria_-_Bellombra,45.011129,12.034126,1994,4,74.4,11.5  
Adria_-_Bellombra,45.011129,12.034126,1994,5,26,17.2  
Adria_-_Bellombra,45.011129,12.034126,1994,6,108.6,20.6
```

Pivot Table:

[image]

Since I am handling various locations, I am iterating over them:

```
locations=pivot.index.get_level_values(0).unique()

for location in locations:
    split=pivot.xs(location)

    rain=split["rain(mm)"]
    temp=split["temp(dC)"]

    plt.subplots()
    temp.plot(kind="line",color="r",).legend()
    rain.plot(kind="bar").legend()
```

An example plot output is shown below:

[image]

Why are my temperature values being plotted starting from February (2)?
I assume it is because the temperature values are listed in the second column.

What would be the proper way to handle and plot different data (two columns) from a pivot table?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would provide your sample data in __text__ form

Comment: certainly! sample data added.

Answer (score 7):

It's because `line` and `bar` plots do not set the `xlim` the same way. The x-axis is interpreted as categorical data in case of the bar plot, whereas it is interpreted as continuous data for the line plot. The result being that `xlim` and `xticks` are not set identically in both situations.

Consider this:

```
In [4]: temp.plot(kind="line",color="r",)
Out[4]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x117f555d0>
In [5]: plt.xticks()
Out[5]: (array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.]), <a list of 6 Text xticklabel objects>)
```

where the position of the ticks is an array of float ranging from *1 to 6*.

and

```
In [6]: rain.plot(kind="bar").legend()
Out[6]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x11c15e950>
In [7]: plt.xticks()
Out[7]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), <a list of 6 Text xticklabel objects>)
```

where the position of the ticks is an array of int ranging from *0 to 5*.

So, the easier is to replace this part:

```
temp.plot(kind="line", color="r",).legend()
rain.plot(kind="bar").legend()
```

by:

```
rain.plot(kind="bar").legend()
plt.plot(range(len(temp)), temp, "r", label=temp.name)
plt.legend()
```

[image: bar line plot pandas]

Comment: ++ for nice solution! Is there a way to do the `range(6)` trick for any x-axis (any kind of data)? I mean a general solution... Maybe save xticks or just it's length?

Comment: @MaxU, Thanks, fixed

Comment: your plot still looks better than mine though ;)
thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [jeanrjc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36136278/6093315) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19969224/6093315) I think I'm finally quite satisfied!

```
for location in locations:
#print(pivot.xs(location, level=0))

split=pivot.xs(location)
rain=split["rain(mm)"]
temp=split["temp(dC)"]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = rain.plot(kind="bar")
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax1.get_xticks(),temp,linestyle='-',color="r")
ax2.set_ylim((-5, 50.))
#ax1.set_ylim((0, 300.))
ax1.set_ylabel('Precipitation (mm)', color='blue')
ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)', color='red')
ax1.set_xlabel('Months')
plt.title(location)
labels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun', 'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dez']
#plt.xticks(range(12),labels,rotation=45)
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
```

I am receiving the following output, which is very close to what I intend:
[image: sample plot]

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the results of a `groupby` operation:

```
for name, group in data[['loc', 'month', 'rain(mm)', 'temp(dC)']].groupby('loc'):
    group.set_index('month').plot()
```

Comment: A more elegant option would be to plot the `groupby` object directly, but I'm not sure how to make it work exactly: `data.groupby('loc').plot()`.